# QCodeDecoder is not defined

Tags: lightning-apps, barcode

I am trying to use jsqrcode in a Lightning component but I am getting an error when the page loads and another when I try to scan an image. I have added qcode-decoder.min.js as a static resource in my org. Any help or tips are greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

#### BarcodeApp.app

```
<aura:application >
     <ltng:require scripts="/resource/BarcodePageResources/qcode-decoder.min.js" />
     <c:BarcodeScanner />
</aura:application>
```

#### BarcodeScanner.cmp

```
<aura:component >
     <aura:attribute name="codeOutput" type="String" />

     <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" aura:id="file" />
     <ui:button label="Scan" press="{!c.scan}"/>
     <br />
     Output : <ui:outputText value="{!v.codeOutput}" />
</aura:component>
```

#### BarcodeScannerController.js

```
({
    scan : function(component, event, helper) { 

        var fileInput = component.find("file").getElement();
        var file = fileInput.files[0];

        var App = {
            init: function() {
                App.attachListeners();
            },
            attachListeners: function() {
                 if(file)
                 {
                     var imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                     App.decode(imgURL);
                 }else{
                     component.set("v.codeOutput","Error: Select file to scan.");
                 }
            },
            decode: function(src) {

                QCodeDecoder().decodeFromImage(src, function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                component.set("v.codeOutput",result);
                });
            }
        };
        App.init();

    }
})
```

#### Error #1

This is the error shown when the page loads:
[image]

#### Error #2

This is the error shown when the scan button is clicked:
[image: Error shown when page first loads.]

I believe it is also worth mentioning that this decoder works in a normal html file, this code is working for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>QCodeDecoder - Image</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>QCode Decoder also decodes directly from an image</h1>

    <img src="chart.png" alt="qr code">
    <button id="decode">Decode!</button>

    <script src="qcode-decoder.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var qr = new QCodeDecoder();

    if (!(qr.isCanvasSupported() && qr.hasGetUserMedia())) {
        alert('Your browser doesn\'t match the required specs.');
        throw new Error('Canvas and getUserMedia are required');
    }

    var btn = document.querySelector('button#decode');
    var img = document.querySelector('img');

    btn.onclick = function () {
        qr.decodeFromImage(img, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;

            alert(result);
        });
    };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is resolved after going into my Salesforce org and navigating to Setup > Critical Updates and deactivating Locker Service. Does anyone know how to make this code work without having to deactivate Locker Service?